# Non-GOT style relocation for executable in GCC

Tags: gcc, linker

In GCC, if I compile something into a shared library with GCC with `g++ -shared func.cpp -o libfunc.so -fPIC`, internal function calls to global symbols go through GOT in this generated shared library file. But if I compile with `g++ func.cpp -o libfunc.so -mcmodel=large`, it will not generate GOT but instead relocate by patching with `R_X86_64_64` style relocation directly.

I want this behavior for executables as well. If I compile an executable with `g++ main.cpp libfunc.so -o a.out`, GCC will generate GOT for any function call from `main.cpp` to one defined in `libfunc.so`. I don't want this behavior. I want `R_X86_64_64` style relocation. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Executables are compiled with `-fPIE` by default in modern distros for security reasons. To get old behavior add `-no-pie` to `CFLAGS`/`CXXFLAGS`.